# Batch file to find .ts files in subfolders, and then move them to a directory?

Tags: batch-file

I found code that will find all .ts files in the subfolders, and then create a log of them. Instead of creating a log, I need to move all of them to a directory so they'll be together. Here is the code I have:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a counter=1
for /r %%i in (*.ts) do (

echo !counter! %%~nxi >> search_result.txt
set /a counter=!counter!+1
)
endlocal
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert into the body of the `for` loop

```
echo(move "%%i" "c:\destination directory\"
```

(in place of the blank line in your posted code)

the result should be a report of which files will be moved.

If the report is correct, change the `echo(move` to `move` to actually move the files.

Note that `echo(` is correct - it's actuall not necessary here (`echo` would suffice) but ensures that if the argument to `echo` is completely empty, a newline is produced,  not an `echo status report`.

Note that `move` will object if the filename already exists in the destination directory, whose name is obviously up to you.

Answer (score 0):

As he said ***"Magoo"***

> If the report is correct, change the `echo(move` to `move` to actually
>   move the files.

```
@echo off
Set NameFolder=TSFolder
Set DestinationFolder=%~dp0%NameFolder%
Set LogFile=search_result.txt
If Not Exist %DestinationFolder% MD %DestinationFolder%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a counter=1
(
for /r %%i in (*.ts) do ( 
    echo !counter! - %%~nxi
    echo(move "%%i" "%DestinationFolder%"
    set /a counter=!counter!+1
    )
)> %LogFile%
endlocal
Start "" %LogFile%
```